# ORACLE APEX / SQL DEVELOPER: Cannot get PK to autoincrement

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex

I am trying to implement my SQLDeveloper DB into Oracle APEX. I cannot figure out how to get the PK's in my table to auto-increment starting from a certain value (i.e. 400001). I have tried making triggers and sequences but when I try to add a row using a form in APEX, my PK increments from 40 for some reason.

Here is my APEX form outcome
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVbwK.jpg)

Here is how it inserts into SQL Developer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwgpR.jpg)

Basically, can someone describe to me how I can edit the existing trigger, or create a sequence, that would make application_id of a new entry auto-increment by 1.

Thanks!

Comment: Show us your sequence and trigger DDL

Comment: version of oracle DB? If 12 or higher you don't need a sequence or trigger at all and can simply use the IDENTITY clause in your PK column definition - similar syntax as your sequence

Answer (score 0):

Find max `application_id`:

```
select max(application_id) From your_Table;
```

Suppose it is `400010` (as screenshot suggests). Now recreate the sequence (presuming its name is `seq_app`):

```
drop sequence seq_app;
create sequence seq_app start with 400011 increment by 1 nocache;
```

Trigger is most probably OK, as you see values being inserted into the table.

Side note: sequences will be unique, but not necessarily gapless. `CACHE` (or `NOCACHE`) might affect that, but - for performance sake, you'd rather let Oracle cache sequence numbers (default is 20) which means that - if you don't use some of those cached numbers, they will be lost. I wouldn't worry, if I were you.

Comment: It is possible to do this without dropping the sequence http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2013/03/reset-sequence-values-to-align-with.html

Comment: Right; requires some more typing (`alter + select + alter`), but yes, it is possible.

Comment: That's why I built a procedure - but you get to keep your privileges, and not break any program units.